# Location blocks in nginx not getting desired outcome - maybe ordering?

Tags: nginx

I've got a website using nginx that's got a load of redirects to retain the juice and UI that old backlinks give me but they're not all working as I need them to. I suspect it could be an ordering issue but I'm not sure so I'd appreciate some help.

I'm pretty sure I'm almost there but I can't work out a way for it all to work together!

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
}

location @redirector {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /redirection-check/?request=$request_uri;
}

location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php;
}

location ~ ^([^.\?]*[^/])$ {
    try_files $uri @addslash;
}

location @addslash {
    return 301 $uri/;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @redirector;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php5.6-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

The way it should work is...

1. If someone lands on domain.com/page or domain.com/page.php then 301 to domain.com/page/
2. Interpret domain.com/page/ as domain.com/page.php
3. If domain.com/page.php doesn't exist then go to domain.com/redirection-check/?request=the404request. This is a 301/404 handler with a BUNCH of old urls in a big php array so they're not all listed in nginx config files.

Comment: It seems to me that you have not fully implemented step (1). Is that the only part that you are having problems with?

Comment: Hi @RichardSmith, that's the main part I'm not sure about. It's probably because I'm trying to do two things at once.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `location ~ \.php$` block to process URIs that end with `.php`. This will handle both internally rewritten URIs (as generated by your `@extensionless-php` block) and externally presented URIs (such as in your 1st requirement).

To handle externally presented URIs differently, you need to look at the original request which is available as `$request_uri`.

The `$request_uri` contains the original request including the optional query string, and can be tested using a `map` or `if` directive.

For example:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^(.*)\.php(\?|$)) { return 301 $1/; }
```

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.